How to detect how long since a user's payment failed?
I'm using Stripe to bill monthly for the use of our website.
I figured out how to retrieve the customer's Subscription object. And I can check the Status property for active or trialing to see if it's currently active.
My question is about when it isn't currently active. I don't want to lock the user out immediately. I want to give them time to try and resolve the payment issue.
So, say I want to give them 10 days to resolve it before I lock the user out. Can someone tell me how I could do this? Is there a date somewhere in the Subscription object that tells me how much time has passed since their billing failed, and I could test whether 10 days has passed?

There's no date on the Subscription itself to indicate how many days have passed since the first failed payment attempt on the latest Invoice. I think you probably want to use the smart retries feature to retry failed payments and mark a Subscription as unpaid after all retries fail. This way, you can continue to allow access to your service if a Subscription is in past_due state but block access once it transitions to unpaid.

Thanks, have you tried this? I see the documentations says "If the first invoice is not paid within 23 hours, the subscription transitions to incomplete_expired. This is a terminal status, the open invoice will be voided and no further invoices will be generated." and "A subscription can only enter a paused status when a trial ends without a payment method." My concern is that not all unpaid subscriptions will end up with the unpaid status.

What I described above is what would happen during the regular cycling of a Subscription that was already active. You're right, if the first Invoice for a brand-new Subscription is not paid within 23 hours, the Subscription never becomes active. If you use payment_behavior: 'default_incomplete', that Subscription transitions from incomplete to incomplete_expired. Trials are also different: a Subscription will be in trialing state during the trial period. If the first non-zero invoice payment fails once the trial is over, the Subscription will transition to past_due.

I recommend using test clocks to test this out: https://docs.stripe.com/billing/testing/test-clocks/simulate-subscriptions
You can also use test card numbers provided by Stripe (specifically 4000000000000341 and pm_card_chargeCustomerFail) attach a card to a customer and simulate a failed payment: https://docs.stripe.com/testing?testing-method=payment-methods#declined-payments
